# StackOverflow error while creating JAXBContext using MOXy in JBoss

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I am using MOXy 2.6 for producing JSON using MOXy JAXB context. at the time of creating JAXB context using jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(beanArray, null); i was getting below error. Please help me to solve the issue.

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:464) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:370) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.JaxbClassLoader.loadClass(JaxbClassLoader.java:107) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaModelImpl.getClass(JavaModelImpl.java:97) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.Helper.getJavaClass(Helper.java:214) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processChoiceProperty(AnnotationsProcessor.java:2485) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processPropertyTypes(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1193) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildNewTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4948) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processReferencedClass(AnnotationsProcessor.java:918) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processChoiceProperty(AnnotationsProcessor.java:2511) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processPropertyTypes(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1193) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildNewTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4948) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processReferencedClass(AnnotationsProcessor.java:918) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processChoiceProperty(AnnotationsProcessor.java:2511) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processPropertyTypes(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1193) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildNewTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4948) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processReferencedClass(AnnotationsProcessor.java:918) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processChoiceProperty(AnnotationsProcessor.java:2511) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processPropertyTypes(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1193) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildNewTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4948) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run outside of JBoss?

Comment: i am getting error in jboss server side alone. dont have problem in client side

Comment: Sorry given the above false comment. thanks. i am getting error in jboss server side but i cant able to determine in client side, because app deployment itself its fails..

Comment: i have tested with old code for Jersey JSON JAXB context for json. in client side i have used Moxy JAXB Context i didnt throw any error. so its problem in server side alone.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the following bug for this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/457127

Can you add additional details to this question and the bug linked above about the model you are using that will help us resolve this issue for you.

Comment: sorry to lately response. when creating create jaxb context, i was passed half of the classes alone to the JAXBContextFactory class. that is the reason i got above error. after i include all the JAXB classes to context it has working now... thanks